# Should I delete the 3rdpartylicenses.txt file in Angular?

Tags: angular

When I build Angular application, the `3rdpartylicenses.txt` file is output in the publish folder.

Can I delete it when publishing to my domain?
Is it mandatory to avoid copyright infringement?
[image]

This is the file content

[image]

If that file is not needed, is there any way to avoid creating the file with each build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `3rdpartylicenses.txt` file is automatically generated by Angular CLI when building an application using the `ng build --prod` command.

This file contains a list of licenses for third-party libraries used in the application. It is not mandatory to keep this file when publishing to a domain, but it is recommended to avoid copyright infringement. If you choose to delete the file, make sure to keep a record of the licenses for all third-party libraries used in the application

**There is no way to prevent Angular CLI from creating the 3rdpartylicenses.txt file with each build.**

However, you can use the `--extractLicenses=false` flag to prevent the license information from being removed from minified JS files